# How to encrypt a license file in PHP with a private key and decrypt in C# with a public key

Tags: c#, php, .net, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt a license file in PHP and decrypt it for verification in an application in C# Sharp but I'm stuck, tried different examples but they either don't work or require a 1MB library
Generating a key pair via:

```
    $dn = array(
        "countryName" => "UA",
        "stateOrProvinceName" => "test",
        "localityName" => "test1",
        "organizationName" => "test2",
        "organizationalUnitName" => "test3",
        "commonName" => "test4",
        "emailAddress" => "test5@gmail.com"
    );

    $privkey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
        "private_key_bits" => 4096,
        "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    ));

    // Create CSR
    $csr = openssl_csr_new($dn, $privkey, array('digest_alg' => 'sha512'));

    // Create a self-signed certificate with a lifetime of 365 days
    $x509 = openssl_csr_sign($csr, null, $privkey, $days=365, array('digest_alg' => 'sha512'));

    // Save in the file
    $filePrivKey = 'private.key';
    openssl_pkey_export_to_file($privkey, $filePrivKey);

    // CSR - Export to file
    $csrFile = 'cert.crt';
    openssl_csr_export_to_file($csr, $csrFile);

    //$x509csrFile crt
    $x509csrFile = 'x509cert.crt';
    openssl_x509_export_to_file($x509 ,$x509csrFile);

    // Publick key
    $pub_key = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents('x509cert.crt'));
    $keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($pub_key);
    file_put_contents('key.pub', $keyData['key']);
```

I encrypt in PHP using a private key

```
    // I’ll get the key to the file
$pathPriv =  'private.key';
$PrivKey =  file_get_contents($pathPriv);

$LicenseKey = '05.05.2020 | example@gmail.com | Nikname';

openssl_private_encrypt($LicenseKey, $encrypted, $PrivKey);

$message = base64_encode($encrypted);

DecryptKey($message);
```

Trying to decrypt in C#.NET Framework

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string pubkey = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"publicKey.xml");
        string message = "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";

        byte[] ciphertext = Convert.FromBase64String(message);
        string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ciphertext);

    }


        public string decrypt(string elementToDesencrypt)
    {
        // string pem = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(pathPublicKey);
        string pem = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"publicKey.xml");
        byte[] Buffer = GetPublicKey();
        System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        System.Security.Cryptography.RSAParameters rsaParam = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
        rsaParam.Modulus = Buffer;
        rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParam);
        byte[] encryptedMessageByte = rsa.Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(elementToDesencrypt), false);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedMessageByte);
    }
```

I am getting an exception "The data size to be decrypted exceeds the maximum for this module, 512 bytes"

Comment: Maybe you are mixing up something. The usual way of ENCRYPTING is to use the PUBLIC key and for DECRYPTION use the PRIVATE key. Whe thinking of a digital SIGNATURE you will use your PRIVATE key for the signature and the PUBLIC key for the verification. Some libraries do accept the other ways but not all.

Comment: Using of Private/Public key encryption limits the length of data that can get encrypted, e.g. a RSA-key of "2048 bit" restricts the plaintext to 245 bytes. If you want to encrypt longer plaintexts you should consider "hybrid encryption" means that the data is encrypted with a 256 bit (32 byte) long AES key [I recommend GCM mode] and the encryption key is encrypted by the PUBLIC key. The decryption will be done with the PRIVATE key and then go on with the (symmetric) decryption.

Comment: Eg: Something like like HTTPS only uses asymmetric encryption to encrypt the _symmetric_ keys that will be used to actually encrypt the data stream.

Comment: @MichaelFehr [link](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.openssl-private-encrypt.php)  openssl_private_encrypt — Encrypts data with private key
I wanted to encrypt the license file and decrypt in the user application.
Is it safe to provide the private key to the user?

Comment: Please overthink the purpose of your encryption - giving the PRIVATE key to the user means he has full access over the licence, can modify the licence and de- and encrypt as he likes. BUT: talking about security management is off-topic here on SO.